# How do I make the PS4 controller vibrate in Unity3D on mac?

Tags: unity, controllers, gamepad

I am currently working on a 2D game in Unity3D with an option to play with a gamepad/controller. I would like the PS4/dualshock 4 controller to vibrate. I am on mac. I have looked into Xinput but I think it is only for Windows, I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, XInput is Windows. Controllers are far from standardized, that's why you're best off using an existing library that offers controller support instead of spending months on your own implementation. One that supports Dualshock 4 vibration on OS X is http://guavaman.com/projects/rewired/docs/SupportedControllers.html